# Organize similar functions in a class

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have a method that gets a matrix of 11xm values (m is variable), analyzes the data and returns an array of features based on that matrix. 
I've already written a long function to process this data, however, I wanted to convert it to a class since I will need to extend it later.

My issue is related to how I should organize some functions.

I thought about having a "get" function for each feature extracted from the raw data.
the problem is that different functions will need the same exact preliminary calculations.

For example, I have many x&y points, and I will first need to calculate the pairwise distances, then velocities, then accelerations, and angles. Then all this data will be used to calculate some features.
For example, in the following, if I need to call preliminary1 for both feature 1 & 2, that's twice the work, and I might actually need the same preliminary calculations for 4 or 5 subsequent features (functions). I might need some more calculations for feature 3 that would also need preliminary 1.
Any ideas on how to do this?

```
private double[] preliminary1(double[], double[]) { some calculations}
private double[] preliminary2(double[]) { 
    value = preliminary1(value1, value2);
    // more calcuations }

public double getFeature1() { 
    value = preliminary1(value1, value2);
    // more calcuations }
public double getFeature2() { 
    value = preliminary1(value1, value2);
    // more calcuations }
public double getFeature3() { 
    value = preliminary2(value1);
    // more calcuations }
```

Comment: Within each function: `if (!preliminary1Valid) { prelimary1(...); preliminary1Valid = true; }`. Invalidate cached preliminary values as necessary (e.g. when you change dependent values).

Comment: Or don't separate the features. `class Features { double feature1, feature2, feature3; }` -> `public Features getFeatures()` or `public void getFeatures (Features f)`.

Comment: I like the first option better. It will allow me to separate the features while generating the preliminary data only once. Thanks.